# java.lang.Throwable at :com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, admob, kotlin-coroutines

Please help me figure it out. Some users have a crush like this:

```
kotlinx.coroutines.CompletionHandlerException: Exception in completion handler InvokeOnCompletion@c1de63[job@7e00a60] for StandaloneCoroutine{Completed}@7e00a60
    at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.completeStateFinalization(JobSupport.kt:320)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryFinalizeSimpleState(JobSupport.kt:295)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompleting(JobSupport.kt:856)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCompletingOnce$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:828)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.resumeWith(AbstractCoroutine.kt:100)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'DefaultDispatcher-worker-5'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 2) {8812c5f} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 2) {8812c5f})
    at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2603)
    at android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript(WebView.java:888)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.evaluateJavascript(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@213806100@213806100057.397311113.397311113:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.aM(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@213806100@213806100057.397311113.397311113:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.aH(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@213806100@213806100057.397311113.397311113:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.f(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@213806100@213806100057.397311113.397311113:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mraid.k.e(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@213806100@213806100057.397311113.397311113:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.al(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@213806100@213806100057.397311113.397311113:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.y.al(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@213806100@213806100057.397311113.397311113)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.render.ba.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@213806100@213806100057.397311113.397311113:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.interstitial.b.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@213806100@213806100057.397311113.397311113:7)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.shim.ah.F(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@213806100@213806100057.397311113.397311113:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.shim.aa.F(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@213806100@213806100057.397311113.397311113)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.bd.bJ(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@213806100@213806100057.397311113.397311113:8)
    at zg.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@213806100@213806100057.397311113.397311113:4)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzov.zzbr(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base@@20.4.0:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbfd.zzQ(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.4.0:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbrw.show(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.4.0:2)
    at com.app_name.utils.ads.Ads.showInter(Ads.kt:73)
    at com.app_name.ui.FragmentDeleting$jProgressBarAnimate$1$1$1$onAnimationEnd$1.invoke(FragmentDeleting.kt:105)
    at com.app_name.ui.FragmentDeleting$jProgressBarAnimate$1$1$1$onAnimationEnd$1.invoke(FragmentDeleting.kt:102)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.InvokeOnCompletion.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1391)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.completeStateFinalization(JobSupport.kt:318)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'DefaultDispatcher-worker-5'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 2) {8812c5f} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 2) {8812c5f})
    at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2598)
    ... 33 more
```

My delete function is called like this:

```
val deletingJob = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    viewModel.selectFilesDeletion { _, _, _ -> }
}
```

When the deletion happened and the animation worked, I call the advertisement:

```
val animProgress = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", progressBar.progress, PROGRESS_MAX)
        animProgress.apply {
            duration = DURATION_ANIMATION
            setAutoCancel(true)
            interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
            start()
            doOnEnd {
                binding.lottieAnimation.addAnimatorListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
                    override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animator?) {}
                    override fun onAnimationCancel(p0: Animator?) {}
                    override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animator?) {}
                    override fun onAnimationEnd(animator: Animator) {
                        if (deletingJob.isCompleted) {
                                Ads.showInter(requireActivity(), this@FragmentDeleting)
                        } else {
                            deletingJob.invokeOnCompletion {
                                    Ads.showInter(requireActivity(), this@FragmentDeleting)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                binding.lottieAnimation.playAnimation()
            }
        }
```

According to the log, I understand that the problem is in the thread in which ads are displayed. The question is if I wrap

```
Ads.showInter(requireActivity(), this@FragmentDeleting)
```

In

```
requireActivity().runOnUiThread{ }
```

Will this solve the problem? Or do I need to somehow rewrite the coroutine, am I new to coroutines, or is this not the case at all?
If it’s not about threads, what then and how can I fix it?